# Shimano downtube shifters 3x7 speed

Tags: shimano, shifter, downtube-shifter

I have an old road bike with 3x7 speed and STI levers. I need to downgrade it because I can't reach the levers due to my small hands.

What downtube shifters can I buy to that will work with my Shimano derailleurs? I'm on a low budget.

Are downtube shifters designed to be indexed only on the rear derailleur? My LBS has a pair of 3x7 downtube shifters and only the rear is indexed.

Comment: One option is to move the shifters up onto the handebar stem -- "stem shifters" were the norm before downtube shifters became popular.  If you can find an appropriate bracket (perhaps used, from a neighborhood bike shop) then likely  the existing shifters can be used (but you'd need longer cables, of course).

Comment: Ya I know but I prefer the downtube option. Simply I'm not understanding if it's normal that a 3x7 speed have the indexing system only on the rear and not on the front. I'd like to find a 3x7 all indexed but it's an hard search.
Recently i found SHIMANO Tiagra SL-R400, but are for 8 speed and I don't know if they works also for 7 speed.

Comment: Presumably you have brake/shift units with the shift levers just behind the brake levers. If you cannot reach the shift levers how are you reaching the brakes? What lever units do you have? Some have reach adjustment.

Comment: I have a pair of shimano rsx STI shifters 3x7 mounted in a 38cm compact handlebar. Its reach is 75 mm and I've a 60mm stem.
I will try to move them in order to find a good comfort, but I'm considering to mount crosstop levers and downtube shifters. I already tried shims and they don't work for my hands.

Comment: Repositioning the brifters on the bars can have a big effect. If you move them a little farther around the curve of the drops, they start to get angled closer to the bars.

Comment: Yeah! I can't wait to try tomorrow! Meanwhile if this solution does not work, which pair of downtube 3x7 shifters will work? As said, I'm wonder if it exists a full indexed pair of downtube shifters for my number of speed.

Comment: In my experience, simple lever-type shifters tend not to be indexed on the "front" shifter because you usually need to trim the front derailleur for different chainlines - you have to move the front derailleur a little bit depending on which rear cog the chain is on in order to prevent the chain from rubbing on the front derailleur.  Heck, I never liked indexed downtube shifters anyway, as non-indexed lever shifters are a lot easier to adjust - as in "never needed" - at least as long as the lever can move the derailleur over the entire required range, anyway.

Comment: Most indexed front shifters are set up for 5-7 positions, and the lever allows two (or more) clicks with one motion.  This (more or less) facilitates "trimming".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7 and 8 speed cassettes have the same spacing, so you can use either in your situation.

As for indexing on the rear, usually there is no indexing, though I've seen 'semi-indexing', where they do have an index mechanism, but it still requires several clicks to switch chainrings.

Additionally, you sometimes need to adjust a little bit based on what gear you have selected in the rear. Spacing between chainrings can vary somewhat on different cranksets, it's not as rigidly specified as it is for the rear.

The 3x7 shifters your LBS should work just fine.